# connect ms sql server with node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, database

I'm new in nodejs
I just want to connect my nodjs app to Microsoft SQL server 2014
anyone help me to know what is wrong in my code, please
this is my code below

```
const sql = require("mssql");

 /*-------------------add details of sqlConfig-----------------*/

const config ={
user: 'sa',
password: '*******',
server: 'localhost',
database: 'test'
};
/******************************************************************/ 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
let connection = sql.connect(sqlConfig,err => {

if(err){
  console.log(err);
}
else{
 res.send('DB Connected');
 //code for sql request here
 const request = new sql.Request();
 app.listen(port,function(){
 console.log('Server started at ${PORT}');
 // SQL Query here
 request.query('select * from Tb...').then(res=>{
 console.log(res);  });

});}
})
})
```

Comment: do you setup port variable?

Comment: Do you get some sort of error?  Do you have a default instance of SQL Server installed on the box where this code is running?

Comment: @AlexYu , Yes Mr.Alex , here is the code of setup: 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on PORT: ${PORT}`);
});

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the connection failed , sure I have installed the SQL server properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First:

I am guessing that you are trying this on your local machine and that you are using the self signed cert from mssql ? If so make sure to set the option `trustServerCertificate: true` in the config object.

#### Second:

The `sql.connect` function is a Promise which you have either to `await` or to use the `.then` `.catch` syntax.

Here a very basic example with `await` syntax:

```js
const express = require('express');
const sql = require("mssql");
const app = express();

/*-------------------add details of sqlConfig-----------------*/

const config = {
  user: "sa",
  password: "duvoia1-rfas+dfc",
  server: "localhost",
  database: "master",
  options: {
    trustServerCertificate: true
  }
};

/******************************************************************/
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await sql.connect(config);
        res.send("DB Connected");
    } catch(err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`service is running on:: [${port}]`);
});
```